# Facebook Flash CS5 integration

Tags: flash, facebook

I am working on a flash game, and I wanted to use some facebook integration in it, but I haven't been able to find anything that explains how to do it, or it flash has a normal facebook api. Can someone here point me in the right direction? Everything I have found is about flex or air, but I need the normal flash cs5. Does anyone know how to add something like that into flash? Thanks for any help you can give me or point me towards.

WWaldo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook.html)? It looks like what you would want.